# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '<b>' to data type float

Tags: sql, sql-server, type-conversion

Here, What I am trying to do is to display the data in `BOLD` and did for `name` column at `backend` and there isn't any issue but when applying same to the `salary` it's raising an error even using `conversion functions`. So, I am looking for your suggestions OR solutions :

The case is same but data and query is different and I must go through the dynamic query as below because it's huge with various conditions.

```
CREATE TABLE #test(name VARCHAR(50), salary FLOAT)
INSERT INTO #test VALUES
('a', 1000),
('b', 5000)

DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(8000)

SET @sql = 'SELECT 
        ''<b>'' + name + ''</b>'',
        ''<b>'' + salary + ''</b>''
    FROM #test'

EXEC(@sql)
```

Thank You.

Comment: @Gordon, @sepupic, Dmitrij Kultasev, I have already applied all these techniques but still getting same issue, if you guys don't mind then I can post screen shoot. Let me correct one thing in question that it's `FLOAT` instead of `INT` but all your solutions working fine in test data. Thank you for such a quick and better solutions.

Comment: There has to be *something* sitting between your query results and a browser that will interpret HTML. Whatever that something (or somethings) is, it's likely **far** better suited to perform formatting tasks than trying to do it down in the database in T-SQL.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever you are right, but unable to fix it since a long time so please have a look in the screen shoot where you guys may find any problem.

Comment: What does the corresponding field on the top half of the union all look like?

Comment: What does line 2 look like, given that's what the error message says.

Comment: All exactly same only the value in `total` column is different in all sets and one thing its working fine, if I remove bold tags from the code. Error message is posted as question title and displayed in image as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE #test(name VARCHAR(50), salary INT)
INSERT INTO #test VALUES
('a', 1000),
('b', 5000)

DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(8000)

SET @sql = 'SELECT 
        ''<b>'' + name + ''<b>'',
        ''<b>'' + CAST(salary AS VARCHAR(20)) + ''<b>''
    FROM #test'

EXEC(@sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast your `salary` to `varchar(100)` explicitly

```
SET @sql = 'SELECT 
        ''<b>'' + name + ''<b>'',
        ''<b>'' + cast(salary as varchar(100)) + ''<b>''
    FROM #test'
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why dynamic SQL is necessary.  However, I often approach such problems using `replace()`:

```
SET @sql = '
SELECT ''<b>''[name]''</b>'', ''<b>''[salary]''</b>''
FROM #test
';

SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '[name]', 'name');
SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '[salary]', 'salary');

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

I also recommend `sp_executesql` over `exec()` -- it is more flexible and allows you to pass parameters in and out of the statement (this functionality is not needed for this query).